# How to run tool with psexec interactively for all logged-in users?

Tags: windows, psexec

I know how to use `psexec` to run a programm interactively for a single session:

```
PsExec.exe -s -i 7 \\computername notepad.exe
```

But I Need to run it for all logged-in users, not just for a specific session.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can list all active sessions with `Qwinsta` command (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/qwinsta)):

```
qwinsta /SERVER:servername
```

Here is a sample output of this command:

[image]

Now you can take all the RDP connections ID from column `ID` and run your commands:

```
PsExec.exe -s -i 0  \computername notepad.exe
PsExec.exe -s -i 1  \computername notepad.exe
PsExec.exe -s -i 17 \computername notepad.exe
PsExec.exe -s -i 19 \computername notepad.exe
PsExec.exe -s -i 32 \computername notepad.exe
PsExec.exe -s -i 39 \computername notepad.exe
PsExec.exe -s -i 40 \computername notepad.exe
PsExec.exe -s -i 55 \computername notepad.exe
PsExec.exe -s -i 69 \computername notepad.exe
PsExec.exe -s -i 70 \computername notepad.exe
```

If you want to automate this process you can:

1. parse `qwinsta` output with powershell (see an example [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/62230523-b3ff-49b1-a59e-6a3325f2339c/qwinsta-other-ways-to-enumerate-rdp-sessions-powershell-and-custom-objects?forum=ITCG))
2. extract connection IDs
3. automatically generate and execute your `PsExec` commands